# onViewStateRestored never called in Android Marshmallow only

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Good afternoon,

I noticed that Android Marshmallow never called onViewStateRestored or onCreate with a bundle not null when I go back on my activity or fragment.
Maybe it have a better memory management. Do you have any documentation about this?

I test on Android before Marshmallow and onViewStateRestored is called.

Best regards